# getting nodes with location specified via NeomodelPoint

Tags: neomodel

getting nodes with location, specified with NeomodelPoint give an error "Invalid instantiation via no arguments", while setting node in the same way works well (below it gives ConstraintError). What is the right way of getting nodes with specific location?

```
location=(51.3454, -6.2434)
try:
    property = Property.nodes.get(location=NeomodelPoint(location,crs='cartesian'))
except:
    property = neo4j.Property(location=NeomodelPoint(location,crs='cartesian')).save()
```

ValueError: Invalid instantiation via no arguments. A Point needs default values either in x,y,z or longitude, latitude, height coordinates

ValueError: Invalid instantiation via no arguments. A Point needs default values either in x,y,z or longitude, latitude, height coordinates

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dmitriy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neomodel/util.py", line 211, in cypher_query
response = session.run(query, params)
File "/Users/dmitriy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 331, in run
self._connection.fetch()
File "/Users/dmitriy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 287, in fetch
return self._fetch()
File "/Users/dmitriy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 327, in _fetch
response.on_failure(summary_metadata or {})
File "/Users/dmitriy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/result.py", line 70, in on_failure
raise CypherError.hydrate(**metadata)
neo4j.exceptions.ConstraintError: Node(2484) already exists with label `Property` and property `location` = {geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [51.3454, -6.2434], crs: {type: link, properties: {href: "http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7203/", code: 7203}}}}

Answer (score 0):

That was a module bug, which is eventually fixed